# Android shell script grep

Tags: android, grep

I'm attempting to write a script using the Android shell (with Busybox) to scan through some .xml files to extract information, however, I'm getting stuck on some optimization.

Shouldn't, for example,

```
(ax)b
```

match to

```
axbxc
```

It doesn't; when I try to execute this on Android (4.2.2, with Busybox 1.20.2, if it matters?).

```
echo axbxc > \sdcard\test.txt
grep "(ax)b" \sdcard\test.txt
```

returns nothing, while

```
grep "axb" \sdcard\test.txt
```

returns, as expected,

```
axbxc
```

Similarly, shouldn't

```
(?>ax)b
```

return axbxc as well? (This is the actual optimization I want to apply.)

What could be causing this problem? Additionally, does anyone know what regex engine Busybox uses, so that I can go and read up on it specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable extended regular expressions in grep (and in busybox grep), you need to either use `grep -E` or use `egrep` (`egrep` is shortcut for `grep -E`).

I have tested this with busybox grep, and both methods work as expected and match your regex.

As for `(?>ax)b` - this would work only if you can use `grep -P` (support for Perl compatible regexes). However, busybox grep does not support this switch, so look-ahead and look-behind matches won't work.

Comment: ... Oh. Thanks. Well, I feel silly now. Do you by any chance know what regex engine Busybox uses?